# I add the fonts success, but in Attributes inspector I can not find it

Tags: ios, fonts

I add the fonts success, and in AppDelegate.m I print the fonts:

```
NSArray *familyNames = [UIFont familyNames];
for( NSString *familyName in familyNames )
{
    NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName];
    for( NSString *fontName in fontNames )
    {
        printf( "\tFont: %s \n", [fontName UTF8String] );
    }
}
```

You can see I add the fonts success, it prints, but in Attributes inspector I can not find the fonts.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I also config the `ttf` in `info.plist`

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**Edit**

I have added the fonts to my Copy Bundle Resources:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After choosing 'Custom' for the font, shouldn't you be looking under the 'family' + 'style' dropdowns?

Also in the project inspector > targets, select your project and look under 'Build Phases' and check that the font is listed in 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

Answer (score 0):

I know your issue (Because I saw the `Family` dropdowns text is gray), when you add your custom fonts, you can not set it immediately.

Because the Family of Custom is disabled:

[image]

But you can switch the Font to System:

[image]

Then come back to Custom, then you can choose the fonts you set from Family:

[image]